# How to add the title of a page to the table of content?

Tags: chapters, abstract

I am trying to write my abstact which is obviously a part of my thesis. However, when I use

```
\chapter{Abstract}

<text of the abstract>
```

Its give me "Abstract" as the title of the page. But the required format in our school is to put the title of the thesis and then the "Abstract" word. So I used the follwoing code

```
\begin{center}
   \textbf{Title)
} \\
\textbf{ABSTRACT}
\end{center}
```

This code works fine, but the Abstract page number will be removed from the table of content. Any help?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `\addcontentsline` to help you here:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

The general form of the command is

```
\addcontentsline{file}{sectionunit}{content}
```

You can find some more details here (for example): http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex2e/latex2e_165.html