# Skip the chapter title but still enter it into the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add the title of a page to the table of content?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59814/how-to-add-the-title-of-a-page-to-the-table-of-content)

I am writing my thesis. I am using a chapter named 'Dedication'. I want to skip the chapter title but still enter it into the Table of Contents. How to do it?

Comment: what do you mean with "skip the chapter title"? Something like `\chapter[Title on the toc]{}`?

Comment: duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59814/6621

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: the solutions may be the same, but the questions that give rise to them are not.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the command

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
```

on the page where the dedication is located. This will insert a line item in the table of contents (toc) even though no corresponding `\chapter` command is actually executed on the page in question. If you want to give the toc less visual prominence than what would be accorded to an entry of type "chapter", you could replace "chapter" in the line above with "section".

**Addendum**: If your document happens to load the `hyperref` package, you should also insert the instruction

```
\phantomsection
```

immediately before the `\addcontentsline` instruction, so that clicking on the line "Dedication" in the table of contents will take the reader to the correct page.

Comment: Wouldn't there need to be a `\phantomsection` or null (or something  else) for the `\addcontentsline` to *attach* to?

Comment: @JohnReed: Assuming the `hyperref` package -- which defines the macro `\phantomsection` -- is loaded, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to insert that instruction. I didn't mention this in the answer because the OP didn't mention he/she was using `hyperref`, so I didn't want to complicate matters needlessly. I'll add a sentence to mention this point, though. For sure, I *am* assuming that the OP is starting the dedication page material on a new page (via either `\newpage` or `\clearpage`) before the `\addcontentsline` macro gets executed.

Comment: Ok I see now. The implied `\newpage` (etc.) wasn't clear to me from the answer since I didn't read the question closely enough. Sounds like a fair assumption to me.

Comment: Instead of `\phantomsection` you can say `\csname phantomsection\endcsname`; this will activate `\phantomsection` only if `hyperref` is loaded but will cause no problem if it is not loaded.